# NSIS changes dir/file ownership on Win platforms

Tags: windows-7, nsis, packaging, file-ownership

I've been using NSIS as a packaging tool on a Windows 7 box.

I've very carefully set the file ownership and permissions to what I want in the source directory.

However, when I perform the packaging and then deploy the package, it has changed all file ownerships to "Administrators".

I originally had the "RequestExecutionLevel admin" but even after removing the line, NSIS continued deploying the files with "Administrators" as the owner.

This is giving me a huge headache.

I'd appreciate any leads on this.

I have deployed the "AccessControl" plugin but haven't found its documentation yet, so that would be useful too.

Comment: You have "deployed" the AccessControl plugin? The documentation for it is in the zip file and on the NSIS wiki...

Comment: Wonderful, I wish I knew that two days ago!

Answer (score 1):

NSIS does not preserve the permissions from your source directory (It would be annoying and would not work on FAT32 and Posix)

There is a group policy setting in Windows that decides if files created by a user in the administrators group belongs to all administrators or just that single user.

```
OutFile Test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user
InstallDir "$Temp\Test"

Section
SetOutPath "$InstDir"

!addplugindir "C:\NSIS\MyDownloadedPlugins\AccessControl\Plugins\"
AccessControl::SetFileOwner "$InstDir" "Anders"
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0

; S-1-5-32-545 is BUILTIN\Users
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$InstDir" "(S-1-5-32-545)" "GenericRead + AddFile + AddSubdirectory"
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0

AccessControl::DenyOnFile "$InstDir" "(BA)" "AddFile" ; Silly example: Don't let people in the Administrators group create new files
Pop $0
DetailPrint $0

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this section on [RequestExecutionLevel](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#arequestexecutionlevel) probably explains my issues with NSIS setting the ownership to admin.

> **4.8.1.34 RequestExecutionLevel**
>
> none|user|highest|admin
>
> Specifies the requested execution level for Windows Vista and higher.
>   The value is embedded in the installer and uninstaller's XML manifest
>   and tells Windows which privilege level the installer requires. user
>   requests the a normal user's level with no administrative privileges.
>   highest will request the highest execution level available for the
>   current user and will cause Windows to prompt the user to verify
>   privilege escalation. The prompt might request for the user's
>   password. admin requests administrator level and will cause Windows to
>   prompt the user as well. ***Specifying none,*** which is also the default,
>   will keep the manifest empty and let Windows decide which execution
>   level is required. Windows automatically identifies NSIS installers
>   and decides administrator privileges are required. Because of this,
>   **none and admin [and default]** have virtually the same effect.
>
> It's recommended, at least by Microsoft, that every application is
>   marked with a required execution level. Unmarked installers are
>   subject to compatibility mode. Workarounds of this mode include
>   automatically moving any shortcuts created in the user's start menu to
>   all users' start menu. Installers that need not install anything into
>   system folders or write to the local machine registry (HKLM) should
>   specify user execution level.
>
> More information about this topic can be found on MSDN.

Basically setting the requested access level to anything other than ***user|highest*** OR not setting it results in everything being set to ***admin***.

My solution will be to set the requested access level to ***user***.